# Word Print/Mail Merge: is it possible to use as datasource a master-detail structure?

Tags: microsoft-word, mail-merge

i've the following excel table:

```
User        Period        Value     
Mike        Jan-March      120
Mike        Apr-Jun        80
Mike        Jul-Sept       100
John        Jan-March      80
John        Apr-Jun        90
 ....
 ....
```

I need to print a single page for each 'User' and the detail inside the page ... example of the word document to print:

```
 Dear Mr. Mike, 
     lorem ipsum .... ....

   Follow your revenue 

      Period       Value
      Jan - March    120
      Apr - Jun      80
     ....

 Thanks for your job
```

As you can see it is a structure "master-detail" .
Can i do using feature Word Print Merge  ?

Answer (score 1):

Word doesn't do this "out-of-the-box", but here are a few things you can try:

A Word adding (template) by Doug Robbins:
https://skydrive.live.com/?cid=5aedcb43615e886b#!/?cid=5AEDCB43615E886B!cid=5AEDCB43615E886B&id=5AEDCB43615E886B%21566

A Word addin by Graham Mayor:
http://www.gmayor.com/ManyToOne.htm

If you need to do it just using Word fields, macropod's tutorial. I think you'll have to subscribe to the site to get this one:
http://windowssecrets.com/forums/showthread.php/111149